# Display ForeignKey attributes in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models:

```
# models.py
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class SiteRatings(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site', related_name='siterating', blank=True, null=True)
    overall_rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    plans_rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    prices_rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    design_rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    support_rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.overall_rating = (self.plans_rating + self.prices_rating + self.design_rating + self.support_rating)/4

        super(SiteRatings, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site.name
```

My views

```
# views.py
def home(request):
    print(user_language)
    site_list = Site.objects.order_by('-date_launched')
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'site_list': site_list}, RequestContext(request))
```

In template

```
# template
{% for site in site_list %}
    <h4><span class="label label-info">{{ site.name }}</span></h4>
    <h4><span class="label label-info">{{ site.siterating.overall_rating }}</span></h4>
{% endfor % }
```

The problem is that when I try to access `{{ site.siterating.overall_rating }}` nothing is being returned, I tried to change for `{{ site.siterating.0.overall_rating }}` and it is not displaying yet.

Comment: Just a FYI - `Site` is a built-in model that comes with the [`django.contrib.sites`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sites/models.py) application. You may not be using it now, but it may cause issues later on. Just be careful of your imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. First in models I created a method to get the site rating (thank you karthikr for your suggestion):

```
#models
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_site_rating(self):
        return self.siterating.filter(site = self)
```

After, I went to my template and used the class method that I had created:

```
{% for site in site_list %}
    <h4><span class="label label-info">{{ site.name }}</span></h4>
    <h4><span class="label label-info">{{ site.get_site_rating.0.overall_rating }}</span></h4>
 {% endfor % }
```

Please, note that I used `...get_site_rating.0...` just because in my case I have just 1 rating/site.